# Define acronyms when running vb code calculating similarity

Tags: vba, excel, similarity, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy

I am utilizing the following vb code in excel to calculate the degree similarity between column A and column B. It runs great.

The next step for me is to define acronyms so the calculated degree of similarity is not impacted. IE: If I have in column A, "ABC LLC" and in column B, "ABC limited liability company", the current vb code will return that the two columns are not very similar. However, I want them to return as 100% similar by defining that "LLC" and "Limited Liability Company" are really the same thing. What can I do and where can I put it in the code to accomplish this? Thanks!

Disclaimer - yes I know there are add-ins to do this. However, my data set is too large to utilize them.

```
Public Function Similarity(ByVal String1 As String, _
                           ByVal String2 As String, _
                           Optional ByRef RetMatch As String, _
                           Optional min_match = 1) As Single

'Returns percentile of similarity between 2 strings (ignores case)

'"RetMatch"  returns the characters that match(in order)
'"min_match" specifies minimum number af char's in a row to match


Dim b1() As Byte, b2() As Byte
Dim lngLen1 As Long, lngLen2 As Long
Dim lngResult As Long

  If UCase(String1) = UCase(String2) Then       '..Exactly the same
    Similarity = 1

  Else                                          '..one string is empty
    lngLen1 = Len(String1)
    lngLen2 = Len(String2)
    If (lngLen1 = 0) Or (lngLen2 = 0) Then
      Similarity = 0

    Else                                        '..otherwise find similarity
      b1() = StrConv(UCase(String1), vbFromUnicode)
      b2() = StrConv(UCase(String2), vbFromUnicode)
      lngResult = Similarity_sub(0, lngLen1 - 1, _
                                 0, lngLen2 - 1, _
                                 b1, b2, _
                                 String1, _
                                 RetMatch, _
                                 min_match)
      Erase b1
      Erase b2
      If lngLen1 >= lngLen2 Then
        Similarity = lngResult / lngLen1
      Else
        Similarity = lngResult / lngLen2
      End If
    End If
  End If

End Function

Private Function Similarity_sub(ByVal start1 As Long, ByVal end1 As Long, _
                                ByVal start2 As Long, ByVal end2 As Long, _
                                ByRef b1() As Byte, ByRef b2() As Byte, _
                                ByVal FirstString As String, _
                                ByRef RetMatch As String, _
                                ByVal min_match As Long, _
                                Optional recur_level As Integer = 0) As Long
'* CALLED BY: Similarity *  (RECURSIVE)

Dim lngCurr1 As Long, lngCurr2 As Long
Dim lngMatchAt1 As Long, lngMatchAt2 As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim lngLongestMatch As Long, lngLocalLongestMatch As Long
Dim strRetMatch1 As String, strRetMatch2 As String

  If (start1 > end1) Or (start1 < 0) Or (end1 - start1 + 1 < min_match) _
  Or (start2 > end2) Or (start2 < 0) Or (end2 - start2 + 1 < min_match) Then
    Exit Function     '(exit if start/end is out of string, or length is too short)
  End If

  For lngCurr1 = start1 To end1        '(for each char of first string)
    For lngCurr2 = start2 To end2        '(for each char of second string)
      i = 0
      Do Until b1(lngCurr1 + i) <> b2(lngCurr2 + i)   'as long as chars DO match..
        i = i + 1
        If i > lngLongestMatch Then     '..if longer than previous best, store starts & length
          lngMatchAt1 = lngCurr1
          lngMatchAt2 = lngCurr2
          lngLongestMatch = i
        End If
        If (lngCurr1 + i) > end1 Or (lngCurr2 + i) > end2 Then Exit Do
      Loop
    Next lngCurr2
  Next lngCurr1

  If lngLongestMatch < min_match Then Exit Function 'no matches at all, so no point checking for sub-matches!

  lngLocalLongestMatch = lngLongestMatch                   'call again for BEFORE + AFTER
  RetMatch = ""
                              'Find longest match BEFORE the current position
  lngLongestMatch = lngLongestMatch _
                  + Similarity_sub(start1, lngMatchAt1 - 1, _
                                   start2, lngMatchAt2 - 1, _
                                   b1, b2, _
                                   FirstString, _
                                   strRetMatch1, _
                                   min_match, _
                                   recur_level + 1)
  If strRetMatch1 <> "" Then
    RetMatch = RetMatch & strRetMatch1 & "*"
  Else
    RetMatch = RetMatch & IIf(recur_level = 0 _
                              And lngLocalLongestMatch > 0 _
                              And (lngMatchAt1 > 1 Or lngMatchAt2 > 1) _
                              , "*", "")
  End If

                              'add local longest
  RetMatch = RetMatch & Mid$(FirstString, lngMatchAt1 + 1, lngLocalLongestMatch)

                              'Find longest match AFTER the current position
  lngLongestMatch = lngLongestMatch _
                  + Similarity_sub(lngMatchAt1 + lngLocalLongestMatch, end1, _
                                   lngMatchAt2 + lngLocalLongestMatch, end2, _
                                   b1, b2, _
                                   FirstString, _
                                   strRetMatch2, _
                                   min_match, _
                                   recur_level + 1)

  If strRetMatch2 <> "" Then
    RetMatch = RetMatch & "*" & strRetMatch2
  Else
    RetMatch = RetMatch & IIf(recur_level = 0 _
                              And lngLocalLongestMatch > 0 _
                              And ((lngMatchAt1 + lngLocalLongestMatch < end1) _
                                   Or (lngMatchAt2 + lngLocalLongestMatch < end2)) _
                              , "*", "")
  End If
                             'Return result
  Similarity_sub = lngLongestMatch

End Function
```

Comment: If you can create an array with the acronyms and their definition (maybe in another sheet?), you can use a check that checks if the value refers to an index/match from the table.  This could be part of a Select Case where the first Case is your typical check, the second Case is this index/match check, and your third Case would be 'is not similar.'  Just an idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without much involvement into your solution, that is your own responsibility, I can suggest some way to incorporate those *Abbreviations*. However. **Please** be aware that this method is not guaranteed 100% success, but you are in the fuzzy world already.

Suppose that we have a `Dictionary` where:

- The keys are the long phrases
- The values are the abbreviations

Before comparing two strings, we *minimize* both of them, by replacing each occurring long phrase by its abbreviation. Then we can compare them with the rest of your method `Similarity` (or by any other method).

```
' Fills an abbreviation dictionary
Sub InitializeDict(ByRef abbrev As Scripting.Dictionary)
    abbrev("limited liability company") = "LLC"
    abbrev("United Kingdom") = "U.K."
    '... Add all abbreviations into dict

    ' Instead of harcoding, you can better load the key/value
    ' pairs from a dedicated worksheet... 

End Sub

' Minimizes s by putting abbreviations
Sub Abbreviate(ByRef s As String)
    Static abbrev As Scripting.Dictionary ' <-- static, inititlized only once
    If abbrev Is Nothing Then
        Set abbrev = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        abbrev.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        InitializeDict abbrev
    End If

    Dim phrase
    For Each phrase In abbrev.Keys
        s = Replace(s, phrase, abbrev(phrase), vbTextCompare)
    Next
End Sub

' A small amendment to this function: abbreviate strings before comparing
Public Function Similarity(ByVal String1 As String, _
                       ByVal String2 As String, _
                       Optional ByRef RetMatch As String, _
                       Optional min_match = 1) As Single

    Abbreviate String1
    Abbreviate String2
    ' ... Rest of the routine
End Function
```

Comment: Think I got it - Thanks so much!

Comment: @jonv Welcome, please keep us updated if implementing this idea (which is actually yours, I only suggested a technical implementation) significantly improved your similarity checker. I'm highly interested ;)

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to check if strings are `Like` each other. For example

```
If "ABC limited liability company" Like "ABC L*L*C*" Then
```

is True as `*` matches any 0 or more characters.

```
Option Compare Text    ' makes string comparisons case insensitive

Function areLike(str1 As String, str2 As String) As Single

    If str1 = str2 Then areLike = 1: Exit Function

    Dim pattern As String, temp As String

    If LenB(str1) < LenB(str2) Then 
        pattern = str1
        temp = str2
    Else
        pattern = str2
        temp = str1
    End If

    pattern = StrConv(pattern, vbUnicode)       ' "ABC LLC" to "A␀B␀C␀ ␀L␀L␀C␀"   
    pattern = Replace(pattern, vbNullChar, "*") ' "A*B*C* *L*L*C*"
    pattern = Replace(pattern, " *", " ")       ' "A*B*C* L*L*C*"

    If temp Like pattern Then areLike = 1: Exit Function

    ' else areLike = some other similarity function

End Function
```